# How to avoid loading Rcpp on every session

Tags: windows-10, r

Ever since upgrading to R 3.6.0, some libraries do not load.  I can get them to load if I perform install.packages("Rcpp").  But i need to do that every time I restart R.  How can I make Rcpp "stick".

In particular using library(aplpack) or library(qcc).

Also notice that the call to library() returns NULL. Trying library(Rcpp) also fails even though it is in the installed packages list

Any help getting this to work would be appreciated.

Additional info:  Once I re-iinstall Rcpp, it no longer appears in the installed packages list. Everything works, but I can't run library(Rcpp).

Comment: Actually the above is a little incorrect.  NO packages can load.  all uses of library(...) returns NULL until I re-install Rcpp

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms led me down the wrong path to solution.  Turns out there was a conflict with the 'conflicted' package. It appears that the update packages button in Rstudio didn't see that 'conflicted' needed an update.  After updating to conflicted-1.0.4, evething works fine.